# Undefined reference to `checkResults'

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, gcc

i have picked up the following demo off the web from https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/apis/users_g5.htm , just to show it like example of functionality of pthread_attr_destroy.

```
#define _MULTI_THREADED
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "check.h"

void *threadfunc(void *parm)
{
  printf("Thread created using an default attributes\n");
  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  pthread_t             thread;
  int                   rc=0;
  pthread_attr_t        pta;

  printf("Enter Testcase - %s\n", argv[0]);

  printf("Create a thread attributes object\n");
  rc = pthread_attr_init(&pta);
  checkResults("pthread_attr_init()\n", rc);

  printf("Create a thread using the attributes object\n");
  rc = pthread_create(&thread, &pta, threadfunc, NULL);
  checkResults("pthread_create()\n", rc);

  printf("Create a thread using the default attributes\n");
  rc = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, threadfunc, NULL);
  checkResults("pthread_create()\n", rc);

  printf("Destroy thread attributes object\n");
  rc = pthread_attr_destroy(&pta);
  checkResults("pthread_attr_destroy()\n", rc);

  /* sleep() is not a very robust way to wait for the thread */
  sleep(5);

  printf("Main completed\n");
  return 0;
}
```

But when i compile it on https://cocalc.com/, with the following commands :

```
gcc name.c -o -lpthread
```

i get this error :

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cceU31Yo.o: in function `main':
attr.c:(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `checkResults'
/usr/bin/ld: attr.c:(.text+0xbc): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: attr.c:(.text+0xd5): undefined reference to `checkResults'
/usr/bin/ld: attr.c:(.text+0xfe): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: attr.c:(.text+0x117): undefined reference to `checkResults'
/usr/bin/ld: attr.c:(.text+0x148): undefined reference to `checkResults'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not doing very well, this is my first contact with programming, and also with Linux, so any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: I believe gcc expects the output file name after `-o` argument. So it could be that your `-lpthread` argument is not parsed properly. Try something like `gcc name.c -o name -lpthread`

Comment: @th33lf I tried it now. It gives me error for : implicit declaration of function ‘checkResults’ and 'sleep' and again  undefined reference to `checkResults'.

Comment: Where is checkResults()? You need to link with that C file or library as well!

Comment: Are you compiling `check.c` along side your current program? `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -o name_you_want -std=c11 -O2 name_of_prog.c check.c`?

Comment: u can code this like keep struct array with pthread function name and return value in loop just check and do accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get `undefined reference to checkResults` is that the compiler cannot find where is the `checkResults` function definition was declared. Since you copied this code from the site, I assumed that you do not have `check.h` file or the checkResults wasn't implemented anywhere.

To fix this, here is a solution:
create a header file called `check.h` with `checkResults()` function definition declared.

```
#ifndef CHECK_H_
#define CHECK_H_

void checkResults(const char* str_ptr, int rc);

#endif
```

create a source file called `check.c` with `checkResults()` function implementation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "check.h"

void checkResults(const char* str_ptr, int rc)
{
    printf("%s returns %i\r\n", str_ptr, rc);
}
```

in your main source file, you need to `#include <unistd.h>` for the `sleep()` function.
when that is all done you can compile with this command:

```
gcc main.c check.c -o main -lpthread
```

Happy Coding!